# saving ggplot figure with limiting megapixels using ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2, resolution, dpi, ggsave

I am trying to save my figure with 900 dpi but at the same time I dont want it to exceed 40 megapixels.

`ggsave(p, filename = 'fig.tiff',dpi = 900,compression = "lzw")`

thanks

i tried `limitsize` option but it is in inches not in pixels

Comment: You should probably just specify the `height` and `width` as well as the `dpi` you want. Or at least say what you want to happen if the default height and width (taken from the current graphic device) result in 40 megapixels or more.

Comment: Suppose your output is more than 49 sq inches (50 inches x 900 x 900 = 40.5 megapixels) -- what should happen?

Comment: thank you guys, I thought there is a way where you can set the megapixel limits and it will set the height and width automatically. I set the `height` and `width` manually and everything is fine. Thanks again